# Best Practice for Master-Detail relationship when ALL combinations are required

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to understand best practice for below scenario:

1) A school can have multiple classes (grades)
2) A school can have multiple events
3) Event is associated with minimum one class  or it can be all school event (i.e. applicable for all classes in the school)

I have typical table structure
Event table (to store events), Class (to store class) and event_class (association table)

1) I insert a row inside 'event_class' table when an event gets associated with class
2) If it is a school event then, assuming a school has 20 classes, I insert 20 records inside 'event_class' table

In theory I know above is correct and would work.

My question is: In case when no of classes get increased from 20 to <>; what's should be the approach? If it is an all school event then shall I just store a flag at header level and use left/right join to get list of events? I am trying to understand what's normally practice.

Thanks in advance
Manisha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this would count as 'Best' practice, but I've certainly seen it a lot in the wild, and therefore is probably at least 'Good' practice.

The Event table should probably have a 'type' column - defined by you, could be numeric or text ('class' or 'school', 0 or 1, etc.). Then, there would only be entries in the event_class table for events of type 'class'.

When retrieving class-specific data for `class_id`, your join logic would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM event, event_class
WHERE event_class.class_id = this_class.id
    AND event.type = 'class'
    AND event.id = event_class.event_id
```

If you wanted all the class AND school event data for `class_id`, it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM event, event_class
WHERE (event_class.class_id = this_class.id
    AND event.type = 'class'
    AND event.id = event_class.event_id)
OR event.type = 'school'
```

Mind the parentheses on the second one to make sure the boolean logic works correctly. None of this is tested I'm afraid - just an idea. There are probably ways of optimising the joins, but for 20 classes, it's likely not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If this has been seen in most of the projects then safely we can say this is the most common practice.